# ASP.NET VS2008 Website Site Application takes so long to load on first load after long idle time

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Just a query I fully understand why my Solution takes so long to load after a build or change to web.config but just wondering. I.e. if I dont access the website for a long time, the site takes a good while to load the first time. After that it goes back to being pretty much instant.

Just annoying that if noone accessing the site for a long time, the first load takes forever making the site seem slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET applications are hosted within an Application Pool. When an app pool has had no requests for a while it gets shut down, to save memory and processing time. When the next request comes in for your application the app pool gets spun up again, which takes a little time.

You can customise how long before an app pool gets shut down by

1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, expand Application Pools,
   right-click the application pool, and click Recycling.
2. Configure the options as you'd like
3. Click OK.